# CSS3 move items to right

Tags: html, css

CSS3 move items to right

The RIGHT column is slightly not equally centered (see screengrab with more light blue space on right). How do I manipulate the CSS to move the RIGHT column with circles and text slightly closer to the edge the same as the LEFT circles?

Move approx 10px to right.

I've currently:

```
 $('#content_index_right ul li:odd').css('padding', '10px 0');
```

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/circle_space2.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/circle_space2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the width of that "center" class so that it's 310px and it will even things out for you:

```
.center{width:310px;}
```

Comment: That's it....it worked .center{width:310px;} Thank you Hillsons. It suddenly worked after refreshing the browsers few times.

Answer (score 0):

this should give your left-side elements an extra margin of 10px to the right:

```
#content_index_right ul li:odd{
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: @Irishgirl Could you create a JSfiddle for us to see what you're doing?

Comment: That's it the it worked .center{width:310px;}
Thank you Brian for your input.